# Unable to get response text of SOAP request

Tags: javascript, soap

Here is the code which is not returning anything. I have used the same SOAP request in SOAP UI and i am getting proper response
only it is not coming in javascript.

```
    var getmarket = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getmarket.open('POST', 'https://www.betfair.com/publicapi/', true);

    var m_request = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" '+
                    'xmlns:bfex="http://www.betfair.com/publicapi/v5/BFExchangeService/" '+
                    'xmlns:v5="http://www.betfair.com/publicapi/types/exchange/v5/">'+
                    ' <soapenv:Header/>'+
                    '<soapenv:Body>'+
                    '<bfex:getAllMarkets>'+
                    '<bfex:request>'+
                    '<header>'+
                       '<clientStamp>0</clientStamp>'+
                       '<sessionToken>Y9eTuEvlrTM55pbRB1kIj0As0bVvz3eFm+p1FY+svHk=</sessionToken>'+
                    '</header>'+
                    '<locale>en</locale>'+
                    '<eventTypeIds>'+
                       '<v5:int>1</v5:int>'+
                    '</eventTypeIds>'+
                    '<countries>'+
                       '<v5:Country>GBR</v5:Country>'+
                    '</countries>'+
                    '<fromDate>2012-08-23TO00:00:00.000Z</fromDate>'+
                    '<toDate>2012-08-24TO00:00:00.000Z</toDate>'+
                 '</bfex:request>'+
              '</bfex:getAllMarkets>'+
           '</soapenv:Body>'+
        '</soapenv:Envelope>';

    getmarket.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    getmarket.send(m_request);
    document.write(getmarket.responseText);
```

Additionally when I use
              document.write(m_request);//the soap envelope

i GET

0Y9eTuEvlrTM55pbRB1kIj0As0bVvz3eFm+p1FY+svHk=
en1GBR2012-08-23TO00:00:00.000Z2012-08-24TO00:00:00.000Z

i.e the data set in between required fields

so is this all right or there has to be better way of doing this?

Comment: Which part of your code does not do the expected?

Comment: is your javascript running under the same domain?

Comment: Keep in mind that `Ajax` is asynchronous.

Comment: Your AsynchronousXmlHttpRequest is *asynchronous* - you know what that means?

Comment: @jbabey no it is not on same domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment `Ajax` is asynchronous so in your `js` you have to do something like:

```
getmarket.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (getmarket.readyState == 4 && getmarket.status == 200)
         document.write(getmarket.responseText);
}
```

`onreadystatechange` event triggers every time readyState changes.

Comment: will this work? because i have added the above snippet and still i get nothing. please advice me on the url to which i am posting. is it correct?

Comment: @user1511443 I see you use post method so you have to set header: `getmarket.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: still i get no response. you are helping a lot. thank you.please get me out of this

Comment: @user1511443 add `alert("State = " + getmarket.readyState + " Status = " + getmarket.status);` before `if`. and see if everything is ok with your request.

Comment: state=1 and status=0. what is the problem?

Comment: @user1511443 `staus=0` means that either access is denied or url is unreachable but because state is 1 it means connection established. Make sure about permissions.

Comment: yes i have used SOAP UI to run this soap request and i get the response. can you tell me  that the url to which i am posting is all right. i have guessed it.

Comment: yes i have used SOAP UI to run this soap request and i get the response. can you tell me that the url to which i am posting is all right. i have guessed it

Comment: @user1511443 It says in Russian that page was not found.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15668/discussion-between-plb-and-user1511443)

Comment: yes i have used SOAP UI to run this soap request and i get the response. can you tell me that the url to which i am posting is all right. i have guessed it